# How to find the minimum value of this function with sinusoidal terms with and without $\pi$ as arguement?

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima, irrational-numbers

I have a function given by:
$$2\cos(100t)+18\cos(2000\pi t).$$ Its maximum value will be at $t=0$ and will be $2+18=20.$

But how one should find its minimum value. Its minimum value can't be $-20$ as:
$$100t=(2n+1)\pi$$
$$2000\pi t=(2m+1)\pi$$
and equating the two terms we have time $t$ at which we get $-20$ to be:
$$\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{100}=\frac{(2m+1)}{2000}$$
which does not seem to be possible as one side is rational and another is irrational, so there is no value of $n$ and $m$ to satisfy these equations.
How should I then find its minimum value?
Can differentiation help? because there also I will get sinusoidal terms.

Comment: as you've already discovered, there isn't a $t$ that actually manages to get both terms to a minumum at once.  You'll have to make do with an approximation.  Allow me to introduce you to [Continued Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).  Note that this does mean you can get arbitrarily close to $-20$...

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer with a little bit of elaboration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no minimum value, but you can get as close to $-20$ as you want.  Because the periods are not rationally related, there is at most one point where the peaks line up.  Here it is $t=0$.  You can find values of $t$ that make it very close to $-20$ but not that hit $-20$

Comment: So basically for any such question of the given format where I have have cos or sine terms and I have to find out a minimum/maximum value, I can safely take the maximum/minimum value of the case when the terms are dealt independently, and I do not need to think about the cycles. For example: for $-200 sin(100t)-36000\pi sin(2000\pi t)$ the minimum value will be $-200 -36000\pi$ and the maximum $200 +36000\pi$

Comment: Minimum and maximum indicate that the value is achieved, so in your original problem there is no minimum.  We use inf and sup to be limits that may not be attained, so the inf of the values in your original problem is -20.  You are right that with incomeasurable periods you can be sure the inf and sup are what you say.  You have to see whether they are attained for minimum and maximum